# How To Present a SKScene from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, skscene

I am creating this game in SpriteKit.
At first launch, the `GameViewController` presents another ViewController called the `MenuViewController` linked with a storyboard. 
And in the `MenuViewController` there is a play button that will present a SKScene called the `GameScene`.

I figured out how to present the `MenuViewController` from the `GameViewController`, but I can't find a way to present the `GameScene` when the play button is tapped. 
In my code, when the button is tapped, nothing actually happens.

`GameViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MenuViewController", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

And in the `MenuViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

         if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill 
            view.presentScene(scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
            view.showsPhysics = false

         }
    }

}
```

Also, I got this warning printed into the console:

`SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler`

I don't know if this is related...

I did set the view of the `MenuViewController`'s storyboard to be equal SKView.
I can't find any way to make the `GameScene` appear. Nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found a solution-I didn't present the `GameScene` directly from the `MenuViewController`, but instead, when the `playButton` is pressed I transitioned to the `GameViewController` and then presented the `GameScene` from there.

I don't know why it doesn't work in the `MenuViewController`, but this method works.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple Devlopment Documentation, 'scene' needs to present for 'view'.
Try this. :)

```
@IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

     if let view = self.view as? SKView {
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        view.showsPhysics = false

        // Add this code
        view.presentScene(scene)
     }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519705-presentscene

Comment: But when I did that, the console printed: `SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler`

Comment: I think you need to check all images or colors name is correct(+upper/lower case).

Comment: for example, `let map = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "map")` code makes those warning message when your image file name is ["M"ap].

Comment: Hi, I actually found out that it presented (or did the stuff in) the scene, but it didn't show up on the display, because I added a print statement in the `GameScene` and when I clicked the playButton it printed the statement. But for some reason nothing actually showed up.

Answer (score 0):

In your GameViewController class change

`if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

to

`if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`